# Styles not being recognized when attempting to change with a google fusion table query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, google-visualization, geoxml3

I have an otherwise working application at [Sample Web Site](http://www.wgianalytics.net/LRTP/index.html?id=511)

I would like to change the display of the selected line from the default thin red line to a much thicker green (or red) line.

When I changed the following code in the map.js file from

```
// Google Fusion LineFeat table
var linLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'name',
          from: linTableId,
      where: idStr,
      },
      map: GlobalMap
    });
```

to add the styles section as shown, nothing changes in the display

```
// Google Fusion LineFeat table
var linLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'name',
          from: linTableId,
      where: idStr,
      styles: [{
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#00FF00",
            strokeWeight: "12"
        }
        }]
      },
      map: GlobalMap
    });
```

Can someone provide me some direction on what I might be doing wrong?  I get these same results if I comment out the call to the zoom.js functions that zoom the map into the specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [styles option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) doesn't go in the query:

```
// Google Fusion LineFeat table
var linLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'name',
        from: linTableId,
        where: idStr
    },
    styles: [{
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#00FF00",
          strokeWeight: "12"
        }
    }],
    map: GlobalMap
  });
```

BTW - in your "Sample Map" you are overwriting linLayer with the layer for AreaFeat, you probably don't want that.